# How to restrict data access to user-defined groups in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, authorization

With MongoDb how can I restrict access to documents - based on user defined groups?

The scenario is a social app like a blog where users create content and others can comment on it.  But I need to allow the content creators to be able to limit access to content (posts) based on specific groups they define (eg Public, Family, Work, Private) where each group also has an access level eg none/read/write.

I'm fairly new to MongoDB/NoSQL.   In a relational db sense I would simply create a join table (linking the many-to-many relationship between user-groups and posts then use an inner join when querying the data.

Thanks.

Comment: So are you planning to let your content creators define groups AND permissions themselves, or are you providing a pre-defined set that they can choose from?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/

Comment: @JooeunLee Ideally I would like it to be a bit like Google Drive, where you can share documents with others - either by granting permission to individuals, to anyone following them or set up groups (so they can reuse these groups for regular assignment of permissions)

Comment: Learned something new, thanks @dnickless

Comment: @TheHuff The $redact idea seems helpful, but I'm not sure if it will be sufficient for your use case. $redact would control access to MONGODB documents, but is that what you want? It sounds like you want to control access to documents a la blog posts, and I'm not sure that filtering out stuff at the database level is what you're aiming for.

Comment: Thanks @dnickless  - I think redact will do the job - if, like the example in the  mongodb docs, I add two array fields in each post to register which user groups have access to the post eg readgroups and writegroups (like the tags field in the example) then at runtime use redact to compare these with the groups the current user belongs to.     @ jooeun-lee I want to exploit at much of the db engine functionality to reduce the need to built it into the app ;-)   I'm currently evaluating MongoDb Stitch - looks fantastic so far.